# Is there any other way other than MLab/ObjectRocket to migrate the app from parse

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, amazon-ec2

I have created an EC2 AWS instance with rocksDb engine now I am trying to migrate the parse application to this Instance as instructed here
https://gyminutesapp.wordpress.com/2016/04/28/migrating-parse-mongodb-to-mongorocks-on-aws

Is it compulsory that I have to do it via MLab/ObjectRockect or is there any other way??

Can Anyone help me out with the further steps, How to connect to parseServer and migrate the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can move to any mongodb database. You can setup any server and install mongodb, allow remote access, and push your data from parse.com to your own mongodb database. This is the first step in parse migration process.

Below are the other steps to take care :
1. Host the open source parse server, configure it to connect to your database.
2. Fix your cloud code, minor changes might be required.
3. Replace the cloud modules that you are using with npm module counterpart.

deploy !!!